# How to use Strapi to store user data

Tags: node.js, e-commerce, strapi, user-data

I am creating an eCommerce platform using strapi. Strapi only has option for user-email and password.
I want to store user's address, contact details, previous orders etc. Is there a way to do so?

I am using the quickstart template.

Strapi version 3.0.0-beta.17.7 (node v10.16.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off course there is a way to do so!

- Go to your admin panel `http://localhost:1337/admin`
- Click on `Content Type Builder` on your left sidebar
- Select `User`
- Click on `Add Another Field`

And add every field you need for your eCommerce platform!

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best way would be to create a `profile` model with a one to one relation to the user. You will need to create your own isOwner policy on the findOne, create, update routes however. This way on that user can view/create/update their own profiles.

Comment: Gotcha!!, I will look into this method as well.